# Как поменять иконку окна

Tags: x11, pascal, c++

Я хочу узнать, как в X-Window с использованием X, XLib, Xutil поменять стандартную иконку X-окна.

Пробовал такой код (писал на FreePascal, но можно и на С++):

```
var bitmap : Tpixmap; 
pxwmhints : TXWMhints; 
scr_Display : PDisaply; 
wnd_handle : Twindow; 
bitmap := XCreateBitmapFromData(scr_display, wnd_handle, 'Icon.xbm', 32, 32);
pxwmhints.flags := IconPixmapHint;
pxwmhints.icon_window := bitmap;
pxwmhints.icon_pixmap := bitmap;
XSetWMHints(scr_display, wnd_handle, @pxwmhints);
```

В итоге иконка меняется на случайный набор пикселей, а не на то, что в файле.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

А формат иконки то какой? xbitmap? ИМХО, я конечно в этом деле полный вася, но размеры у Вас не проставлены.

```
#define test_width 16#define test_height 7static char test_bits[] = {0x13, 0x00, 0x15, 0x00, 0x93, 0xcd, 0x55, 0xa5, 0x93, 0xc5, 0x00, 0x80,0x00, 0x60 };
```

Вот что сказал мне манул, может поможет

Comment: bitmap := XCreateBitmapFromData(scr_display, wnd_handle, 'Icon.xbm', 32, 32);размеры иконки есть(последние 2 параметра) - 32х32, а формат xbitmap т.к именно етот функция поддерживает!0x13, 0x00, 0x15, 0x00, 0x93, 0xcd, 0x55, 0xa5, 0x93, 0xc5, 0x00, 0x80,0x00, 0x60 }; -А это судя по всему и есть картинка, только расписанная по битам.Да, если юзать этот метод, то результат будет, но у меня цель - импортировать данные из файла, что успешно провалилась) Интересно, как в других unix  приложениях юзают форматы ico, bmp, png..? по моему кроме стандартных функций Х юзают что то ешо!